# Crossover Cable 2 Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I have a crossover cable. I want to move files and folders between my two Ubuntu's. I have partially set this up. They can ping each other. But when I use putty the connection gets refused with no other detail given. 
How can I allow the connection to take place?
UPDATE: the two ip's are 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2
both computers have putty. i am using one computer to connect to the other.
1 to transfer files to 2. i don't have a firewall that I'm aware of. i would like to transfer using ssh I guess but I'm open to suggestions.

UPDATE:

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13150    1619/gnome-keyring- /run/user/1000/keyring-Wr33VU/ssh
```

Comment: Is an SSH server running on the target machine? is the SSH port open (not firewalled)? FWIW if you use the native SSH client instead of PuTTY, you can increase the debug level (e.g. `ssh -vvv user@hostip`), which may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: ssh -vvv 10.0.0.1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.1 [10.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: @claghorn please do not reply in comments but instead [update your Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/202120/edit). The formatting is better, for starters, and it also means that updates don't get lost in a comment thread.

Answer (score 4):

Your `netstat` command shows that you are not running an `ssh` server on the target machine. You need to install this from the repository; on Ubuntu it's called [`openssh-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/openssh-server). Installation will automatically start the daemon.

After it has been installed, you should get output something like this, which shows that the `sshd` process is `LISTEN`-ing on port `22`:

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      861/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      861/sshd
```